How to enforce the .editconfig file not to change brace styles?
I want to ensure that existing brace styles in my project are preserved (some braces on the same line and some on a new line).
Here's a snippet of my .editconfig file
[*.cs]
indent_style = space
tab_width = 4

After running dotnet format all braces get moved to a new line. How to enforce brace styles to remain as-is?

I don't know if that is, and it would be against the idea of using a formatter, which, after all, should format the code consistently. Looking at the configuration properties, you could try curly_bracket_next_line = unset or indent_brace_style = unset.
